# How can I add RSS feeds to the windows 10 news app?

Tags: windows-10, rss

Windows 8 news app version had the option of adding personalized RSS feeds. I can't find anything similar in Windows 10 version. Can it be done? Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: In order to avoid offering solutions you may have already looked into, please tell us what research you have done.

Comment: If you can find no feature and or option to add a RSS feed the most logical conclusion is that the Windows 10 version of the application does not support it.  There are significant architectural differences between the two applications so feature parity isn't guaranteed.